# Adding fragments to older Android apps

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to upgrade a couple of my Android apps to use Fragments.  Here is a basic situation:

I have an Activity and a ListActivity.  I want to convert these using fragments using the compatibility packaging.  Below is what I have in the onCreate method in the Activity.  (The ListActivity has similar items so I am only using the Activity as the example ere in the conversion).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.rate);

    Item = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
    Category = getIntent().getExtras().getString("category");

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRateItem);
    ratingsBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.theRatingBar);

    title.setText(Item);

    // Display list of reviews

    new starTotalTask().execute();
    new starRatingTask().execute();

    final EditText etTweetReview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTweetReview);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.theRatingBarButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // do stuff

            }
        }
    });

    Button BReviews = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReviews);
    BReviews.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        // do stuff 

        }
    });

}
```

So you see, I have a couple of Buttons, a couple of AsyncTasks, some getIntents that are grabbing data from other Activities, some "widget" declarations referencing to the XML.

I have the basic framework already setup with a FragmentActivity (from compatibility v4 package) with a couple of fragments it points to.  In fact, I have a ViewPager, and tabs set up.  The correct layouts are already setup as it should be to the new Fragment view.  I just don't get how to move the data as seen above.  I also understand the onCreateView is where you set the layout.  Outside of that, where does everything else go?  Not looking for code example as much as direction -- IF POSSIBLE.

Edit: My layout is based on this:  http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/

especially interest in:
- Where do the RatingsBar and TextView (and other xml references) go?
- what about AsyncTask?
- and how do you handle passing around data in intents?

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything will be identical. The key differences are:

1. You need to extend `FragmentActivity` in place of `Activity`.
2. You need to call `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.
3. You need to call `getSupportLoaderManager()` instead of `getLoaderManager()`.
4. The compatibility library does not support a `ListFragmentActivity` (or whatever). You'll need to use a `FragmentActivity` instead and set up the `ListView` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Not sure if you answered the specific questions? "Everything will be identical" -- so I move that block of code up top from my Activity to Fragment? (not working, I tried), or Activity to Fragment Activity? (I also included link on my layout from a tutorial it is based on)

Comment: If you already have the `ViewPager` + `Fragment`s working w/ the public SDK, transitioning to the support library is just a matter of changing the code I suggested in my answer. I never said you should move your `Activity` code to your `Fragment` code... I said you should use `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`. Your code should follow the same structure as before... you just need to make sure you change the 4 things above (and also make sure you import the correct `support.v4` libraries too.

Comment: Of course, the only change to your code's structure will be altering the `ListActivity` code so that it extends `FragmentActivity` instead. This will also look almost identical to the code you would have written if you had initially had extended the `Activity` class instead of `ListActivity`. Hopefully I am making some sense here...

Comment: Check out the official doc on Fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html It's quite extensive and thorough. I also had to reformat my application to work with Fragments just recently.

Comment: @KickingLettuce if you are talking about transitioning from using no `Fragment`s to using them in your app, then that is a completely different story. The structure will be a lot different... and chances are a lot of the behavior in your `Activity`s will be moved to your `Fragment`s instead.

Comment: @Alex Lockwood Yes, I think that is why I was confused -- I have no fragments at all.  The Activity and ListActivity I would like displayed in tabs (like link above), not split view. I think the original question may be too loaded for here.  I will settle for a good tutorial on the subject.  Been searching for a couple days and haven't found much. Everything shows how to set up the layouts (which I have done); not much discussed on what I've asked above (from what I have seen).